# How to stop a root directory being deleted if incorrect URL is submitted using REGEX

Tags: php, regex

I have an application where I search directories for the files I need and then delete them when consumed.  The problem I have is that sometimes (through the user cancelling a submission) I can get a URL that does not include the search directory and the root directory can get deleted.  My application recreates the root directory on submission if missing, but I would like to put a safeguard in place so that it does not happen in the first place.

In the example below, the last 3 cases will delete the root directory.

Can anyone please help me figure out how I might implement a REGEX function with say `check_function()` that would solve my problem.  I have tried some string manipulation but it is rather crude and would prefer to do it with a REGEX function with which I have very little if no experience.

```
   $delete[] = "c:\\temp/root/abcdefg";
   $delete[] = "c:\\temp/root\\zsyrefg";
   $delete[] = "c:\\temp/root/";
   $delete[] = "c:\\temp/root\\";
   $delete[] = "c:\\temp/root";

   foreach ($delete as $dir) {
        if ($dir!= check_function($root))
            removeDirectory($dir);
   }
```

Comment: would it not be better to check if the submission was cancelled, and if so do nothing?

Comment: It is a very complicated application and a lot of things can go wrong and some ajax calls exit if there is an error, so it is hard to predict where the incompleteness will arise and it is best just to exit and terminate - and of course this leaves loose ends which I clean up post.  I  partly overcome this problem by making sure that the directory now exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this. Here is a possible solution:

```php
function isRoot($dir)
{
    $dir = str_replace('\\', '/', $dir);
    return rtrim($dir, '/') == 'c:/temp/root';
}

var_dump(isRoot("c:\\temp/root/abcdefg"));
var_dump(isRoot("c:\\temp/root\\zsyrefg"));
var_dump(isRoot("c:\\temp/root/"));
var_dump(isRoot("c:\\temp/root\\"));
var_dump(isRoot("c:\\temp/root"));
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Alternatively you could define this function:

```php
function normalizedDir($dir)
{
    $dir = str_replace('\\', '/', $dir);
    return rtrim($dir, '/');
}
```

and test if `normalizedDir($someDir)` is equal to `normalizedDir($root)`.